# How to see the value of a widget?

Tags: user-interface, openedge, progress-4gl

This might seem very obvious, but I'm having trouble with the following thing I want to do:

I put a value in a fill-in field, and I want to see this on screen (the field is part of a frame):

```
ON <some_event> OF <another_widget> IN FRAME <correct_frame_reference>
         ASSIGN fi-Value = -1.
         DISPLAY fi-Value.
```

As far as I understand, this would do the following:

The `ASSIGN` moves the value from the screen buffer to the record buffer.
The `DISPLAY` moves the value from the record buffer to the screen buffer (in other words, the value should be seen on screen).

This works, but the whole frame gets deleted, and I only see the following screen (instead of my entire frame):

[image]

What do I need to do in order not to lose the whole window/frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DISPLAY inside your trigger has no frame name (using a WITH) so it creates a new unnamed frame (and seems to have put it on top of anything else).

You should add "WITH FRAME <correct_frame_reference>" or, depending on why you are displaying the value from within the trigger, you might be better off using MESSAGE.

Answer (score 0):

```
ON <some_event> OF <another_widget> IN FRAME <correct_frame_reference>
         ASSIGN fi-Value = INPUT FRAME  <correct_frame_reference> <another_widget>.
         DISPLAY fi-Value.
```

Comment: Please don't just post code as answers, also include some explenations and clarifications.